Incorrect display of default layout and main context in Nuxt 3 + Vuetify 3 app
In my Nuxt 3 + Vuetify 3 app there are two layouts: default and auth.
app.vue
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

layout/default.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
  const isLayoutReady = ref(false);
  onMounted(() => {
    isLayoutReady.value = true;
  });
</script>

<template>
  <v-app class="default-layout">
    <v-app-bar>...</v-app-bar>
    <Sidebar v-if="isTabletOrDesktop" />
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <div v-if="isLayoutReady">
          <slot />
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

layout/auth.vue
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-row fluid class="auth-layout ma-0 pa-0">
        <v-col cols="12" md="6" class="auth-layout__context">
          <slot />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </main>
  </v-app>
</template> 

pages/transactions/index.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
  definePageMeta({
    layout: 'default',
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div class="transactions">...</div>
</template>  

pages/login.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
  definePageMeta({
    layout: 'auth',
  }); 
</script>

<template>
  <v-card class="login mx-auto pa-5" elevation="0">...</v-card>
</template>

When I navigate from the login page to the transactions page, the main context from the main tag is first displayed on the screen, and then the default layout is displayed. As a result, the header and sidebar overlap the main context.
Adding conditional rendering using the "isLayoutReady" variable does not solve the problem.
How can I set the default layout to be displayed first and then the main context, or both at the same time?
